# Is there a way to replace the bottom part of wall?

Tags: walls

The bottom plate of an exterior wall is rotted quite a bit, is there any way to safely replace it, "DIY-style"?

It's a standard 2x4 wall, and I'm already tore into the inside-side to replace sheetrock.

Comment: Is it load bearing?

Answer (score 3):

This sort of work requires temporary shoring. What that entails varies greatly by what sort of loads the wall is supporting, both vertical and horizontal (such as wind). The fact you are asking at all implies you need professional assistance. Not necessarily to do all the work, but at least to ensure what work is done is done safely and properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.  Its an exterior, wall on the first floor of a two story that parallels the joists (seems wrong to say "non load-bearing" in this sense").  Is there anything I could treat the wood with as opposed to attempting a replace that might help in some way? (Not ideal, I know, but funds aren't going to allow me to do this the "proper" way)